# Spring MVC Sending Model data from View to Controller without having a form

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller

I got two pages that one displays data and other serves as an edit page of fields. I display model data in my first view. If a user clicks edit button, then other view takes control. Here is my problem: hence I dont need any form element in my first displayer page, I can not pass model data to the second view (editter page). Is there any efficient way of passing data from view to controller without adding form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring MVC pass same object between controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426519/spring-mvc-pass-same-object-between-controller)

The best rated answer in this thread might give you a clue.

Comment: adding @ModelAttribute("attributeName") to my second view handler controller (edit page) solved the problem. Thanks.