# Spring Boot object between controller in different class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to get a object sent to a Spring-boot controller in one Class to be available in the model of another controller.

It seems like `@SessionAttributes` is for objects that are global (like the logged on user).

I have tried this on **controller 1**

```
@Component
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "user"})
public class FormController {

    @GetMapping("/occurence/{occno}")
public String findOcc(@PathVariable String occno, OccViewModel occViewModel, Model model) {

    Occ occ = occRepository.findByOccno(occno);
    occViewModel.setOcc(occ);
    occViewModel.setPersons(occPersonRepository.findOccPersonByOcc(occ.getId()));
    List<OccPerson.OccRole> occRoles = Arrays.asList(OccPerson.OccRole.values());
    model.addAttribute("occRoles", occRoles);
    model.addAttribute("occViewModel", occViewModel);
    model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
    return "occ";
}
```

I have a button on this form which sends the user to this endpoint - I would like the same occViewModel to available to this endpoint on **controller 2**

```
@Component
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "user" })
public class PlanController {

@GetMapping("/newplan")
public String newPlan(Model model, OccViewModel occViewModel, HttpSession session) {
    // create PlanViewModel DTO
    Occ occ = new occVieModel.getOcc();
    PlanViewModel planViewModel = new PlanViewModel;
    planViewModel.setOcc(occ);
    model.addAttribute(planViewModel);
    //etc
}
```

I see there is @SessionAttributes but  i do not understand in my first controller how I would even load it into the session if I dont know what Occ to get from the repo as it appears you need to @ModelAttribute prior to the handler - but the URI gives the occno?

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426519/spring-mvc-pass-same-object-between-controller) also but it appeared do deal with the same class only and it wasn't clear how you would apply this to a id passed in on the URI.

Comment: `@SessionAttributes` is for temporary storing objects in between requests. It isn't meant to store objects for the lifetime of your application. If you really want it to have stored permanently just stick it in the `HttpSession` else just pass the id to the next controller (looks like you are only interested in the `occ`. You generally shouldn't be sharing models. Also do you really need 2 endpoints? I would expect something like this `/occurence/{occno}/newplan` and be in the same controller (judging from what you are trying to do in the other controller).

Comment: Excellent answer thanks which I am now using. Are you also saying that onc handler  ( /occurence/{occno}/newplan ) could serve requests to both /occurence/{occno}  and  /occurence/{occno}/newplan ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working correctly to retrieve a object from the database, put it in session and send via GET to the view. The view then later POST the data back to the handler and the object coming back from view is hydrated against the object in session (before being passed to Hibernate).

There is a POST and GET controller for OccViewModel. The @SessionAttributes means that between a Get and a Post the object is held in session and I do not need to pass the object id in hidden tags.

```
@Component
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "user", "occViewModel" })
public class FormController {

@PostMapping("newOcc")
public String occSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("occViewModel") OccViewModel occViewModel, BindingResult result, Model model
HttpServletRequest request, SessionStatus status) {
        // NEW OCC
        if( occViewModel.getOcc().getId() == null ) {
        occService.saveNewOcc(occViewModel.getOcc(), occViewModel.getPersons());
        }
        //UPDATE OCC
        if( occViewModel.getOcc().getId() != null ) {
            occService.updateOcc(occViewModel.getOcc(), occViewModel.getPersons());
        }
    }
    status.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/dashboard";
}

@GetMapping("/occ/{occno}")
public String findOcc(@PathVariable String occno, OccViewModel occViewModel, Model model) {

    // POPULATE OCC VIEW MODEL
    Occ occ = occRepository.findByOccno(occno);
    occViewModel.setOcc(occ);
    model.addAttribute("occViewModel", occViewModel);
    return "occ";
}
```

I believe that OccViewModel must be passed as a parameter into POST and GET handlers.

In terms of then passing this object to another handler in another controller which was done for the sake of keeping the project tidy:

```
@Component
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(value = { "user", "occPlanWork" })
public class PlanController {

    @GetMapping("/occ/{occno}/plan")
public String findPlan(@PathVariable String occno, OccPlanWork occPlanWork, Model model) {

    // GET OCC FROM OCCNO
    Occ occ = new Occ();
    occ = occRepository.findByOccno(occno);

    // SET EPT DATA
    occPlanWork.setOccno(occ.getOccno());
    occPlanWork.setStart_date(occ.getStart_date());
    occPlanWork.setOccId(occ.getId());

    // CREATE NEW PLAN IF BLANK
    if (occ.getPlan()== null) {
        Plan plan = new Plan();
        occPlanWork.setPlan(plan);
    }
    if (occ.getPlan()!=null) {
        Plan plan = new Plan();
        plan = occ.getPlan();
        occPlanWork.setPlan(plan);
    }

    // SET THE EXISTING WORKS (AND CONVERT SET<WORK> TO LIST<LIST> FOR TH COMPATABILITY)
    if (occPlanWork.getPlan().getId()!=null) {
        List<Work> works = new ArrayList<>(occPlanWork.getPlan().getWorks());
        Collections.sort(works);
        occPlanWork.setWorks(works);
    } // CREATE NEW WORK LIST IF PLAN IS NEW
    if (occPlanWork.getPlan().getId()==null) {
        List works = new ArrayList();
        occPlanWork.setWorks(works);
    }

    // RETURN EPT
    model.addAttribute("occPlanWork", occPlanWork);
    return "newplan";
}
```

That was achieved by passing the occurrence number in the URI to the other controller. Again the object backing the view (occPlanWork) is in Session Attributes on the controller level.

Comment: How do you inspect whats in SessionAttributes between Get & Post?